Symmetry In Electrostatics
So I'm new to electrostatics and the whole symmetry thing ,but when I started learning about gauss law I encoutered some problems that requires symmetry in ordre to solve them like the electric field of an infinite cylinder where they stated that for symmetry reasons the electrical field is radially distributed and it's zero along the axis. Well, I don't get it why it's zero due to symmetry ,so if I take a point on the base of a cylinder would the electrical field in that point equals to zero? why is it not just constant? the way i see it is like this


To use the symmetry argument, the charged cylindrical shell should be infinitely long. If it is infinitely long, then there is no natural place in your picture for the arrows to change from pointing "up" to pointing "down", so the field should be zero (at least the component pointing up or down should be zero). For a finite cylindrical shell with two end caps, your picture is actually roughly correct, although the details get messy near the boundaries of the caps. I'm leaving this as a comment since I'm not entirely sure what you have in mind with your picture.

so you're saying since there is no preferred direction for the field it must be zero.Should i just admit that and go on or is there a reason behind this because i am not seeing anything related to summetry here. I'm lost

Suppose you had an infinitely long cylinder laid along the $z$ axis. Suppose for the sake of argument that the field points in the $+z$ direction. Now if you reflect the cylinder about the $xy$ plane, the cylinder comes back to itself, so the field produced by this cylinder must be the same. However, a $+z$ field gets reflected into a $-z$ field. That's a contradiction so there must not have been a component along the $z$ axis. Now you could say that the field was $+z$ in the upper half plane and $-z$ in the lower half plane to get around that reflection argument, but (...)

(...) since the cylinder is infinitely long I also could have reflected around the $xy$ plane at $z=1$, and this would rule out that potential counterexample. Does that make sense? The idea is that a symmetry transformation that leaves the charge distribution invariant, must also leave the field invariant. This fact forces some of the components of the field to be zero, since if those components of the field were non-zero, they would break the symmetry.

As also mentioned in the comments, the cylinder has to be infinitely long for the symmetry argument to work. Think about it like this:

Suppose the an electric field at the point $\mathbf{x}_0$ on the cylinder's axis is $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}_0)$. Decompose the field in terms of components perpendicular to ($\mathbf{E}_\perp(\mathbf{x}_0)$) and along ($\mathbf{E}_\parallel(\mathbf{x}_0)$) the cylinder's axis, such that $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}_0) = \mathbf{E}_\perp(\mathbf{x}_0)+ \mathbf{E}_\parallel(\mathbf{x}_0)$.
Now the cylinder has rotational symmetry around its axis, i.e. if I rotate around the axis by an arbitrary angle, everything in the problem stays exactly the same. The only way for the $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}_0)$ to also stay the same is for its transverse component to be zero. So we conclude that  $\mathbf{E}_\perp = 0$.
Similarly, the infinite (!) cylinder has reflection symmetry along the plane perpendicular to its axis and passing through $\mathbf{x}_0$. This means that if I flip the cylinder around that plane, everything in the problem stays the same. For $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}_0)$ to also stay the same, it needs to have a zero longitudinal component, i.e. $\mathbf{E}_\parallel(\mathbf{x}_0) = 0$.
Since $\mathbf{E}_\perp(\mathbf{x}_0) =\mathbf{E}_\parallel(\mathbf{x}_0) = 0$, we conclude that $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{x}_0) = 0$.

Out of the above, only steps 1 and 2 apply to a finite cylinder. So, as you say, you can have a non-zero longitudinal component in that case.
